# On the subject of holomorphic functions on an open disc, D.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

The question I am pondering over is an interesting one:

If $f(z) = u + iv$ is holomorphic on an open disc $D$, and the range of $f$ lies in either a straight line or a circle, prove that $f$ is constant on $D$.

Do I just need to just Cauchy-Riemann?

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann doesn't really help.  To show that $f$ is a constant, you will need to show $f$ is bounded on $D$.  Liouville's Theorem might help.

Comment: NasuSama, Liouville theorem is applying to entire functions, not the case here...

Comment: Yeah, and also cauchy-riemann equations DO help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Case I.** *The values of $f=u+iv$ lie on a straight line.*

Thus there exists $a,b, c\in\mathbb R$, with $(a,b)\ne (0,0)$, such that
$$
au+bv=c.
$$
Thus, if we set $$g(z)= (a-ib)f(z)=(a-ib)(u+iv)=(au+bv)+i(av-bu)=c+i(av-bu),$$ then $g$ is also holomorphic and
$$
\mathrm{Re}\,g(z)=c.
$$
But is the real part of $g=\alpha+i\beta$ is constant, then due to Cauchy-Riemann equations
$$
0=\alpha_x=\beta_y, \quad 0=\alpha_y=-\beta_x,
$$
the imaginary part of $g$ is also constant, and hence $g$ is constant.

**Case II.** *The values of $f$ lie on a circle.*

Say
$$
f(z)\in \{w: |w-w_0|=r\}.
$$
Set
$$
g(z)=f(z)-w_0.
$$
Then the values of $g=u+iv$ line on the unit circle, and hence $\lvert g \rvert=r$, which implies that $g$ is constant, and so is $f$.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped!

Answer (score 4):

It's a basic fact in complex analysis that a non constant holomorphic function is open...

Comment: This is really the best answer.  The way to understand these sorts of statements is not through detailed calculations tailored to the particular problem, but just by understanding the behavior of holomorphic functions generally.

Comment: I think there is merit in "basic" proofs that avoid using big theorems that are a lot harder to prove than the statement you trying to prove.  Plus, if you see my answer, for example, the calculations are pretty trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the Cauchy-Riemann equations and the partial derivatives of either $u^2+v^2=r^2$ or $au+bv=c$ to form a homogenous 4x4 system for the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$. Then show that it is regular ($r>0$ resp. $a^2+b^2\ne0$ required, $r=0$ is trivial) to conclude that the functions are constant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elementary method using only cauchy riemann equations:

For the first part, rotate to assume the function has image contained in the reals.  Then by cauchy riemann equations the derivative is zero since the partial derivatives of the imaginary part are obviously zero.

For the second part translate to assume that $|f|$ is constant.  So use $c=|f|^2=f \bar{f}$ to get that either $f$ is zero or $\bar{f}$ is holomorphic.  Then apply cauchy riemann equations to prove that if $f$ and $\bar{f}$ are both holomorphic then the derivative of $f$ is zero.

Of course this trivially follows from the open mapping theorem also.